# How can I load external CSS files in AMP

Tags: css, amp-img

How can I load external CSS files like bootstrap.css and other external stylesheets to an html file having AMP?
I checked AMP documentation. but didn't got a solution. I have to do SEO for a PHP static site and I am new to AMP and SEO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AMP requires inline CSS for performance reasons.

https://amp.dev/about/how-amp-works/

https://amp.dev/documentation/guides-and-tutorials/develop/style_and_layout/style_pages/